# Adding a variable to the database

Tags: php

I am trying to add a variable to the database with an bootstrap editor. I have for example something like this :

```
$templateName = $_POST["templateName"]; 
$emailFrom = $_POST["emailFrom"];   
$emailSubject = $_POST["emailSubject"]; 
$emailContent = $_POST["emailContent"]; 

if(mysqli_query($kon, "INSERT INTO emailtexts VALUES (NULL, '". $templateName ."', '". $emailFrom ."', '". $emailSubject ."', '". $emailContent ."')")){
    echo "Added";   
}
```

Where $emailContent is something like this : *This is my content with a variable **$var*** and then in the file where I want to show the result I have something like this :

```
$var= "This is value of my variable";

$rez = mysqli_query($kon, "SELECT * FROM emailTexts WHERE id = 2");
$red = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rez);

echo "Test result : <br /><br />" . $red["content"];
```

And I want to get something like :

> Test result :
>
> This is my content with a variable **This is value of my variable**

But I am getting

> Test result :
>
> This is my content with a variable **$var**

Any suggestions? Thanks.

UPDATE

My php form is :

```
<div class="box-body">
<p class="help-block" style="text-align:center;color:#f00;">Alle velden moeten ingevuld worden!.</p>
<div id="addedSuccess" class="alert alert-success col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" style="text-align:center;display:none;"></div>
<div id="addedError" class="alert alert-danger col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" style="text-align:center;display:none;"></div>
<form id="frmAddTemplate" role="form" action="" method="post">
    <div class="form-group col-lg-6" style="float:none;margin:10px auto;">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtTemplateName" name="txtTemplateName" placeholder="De naam van de email template">
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    <div class="form-group col-lg-6" style="float:none;margin:10px auto;">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtEmailFrom" name="txtFromEmail" placeholder="Sender (from email)">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-lg-6" style="float:none;margin:10px auto;">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtEmailSubject" name="txtEmailSubject" placeholder="Subject">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <textarea class="bs-texteditor form-control" rows="12" placeholder="Email content" name="txtEmailContent" id="txtEmailContent"></textarea><br />
    </div>
    <div id="pleaseWait" style="float:right;margin:4px 0 0 3px;display:none;"><img src="../img/ajax-loader-small.gif" title="Please wait"/></div>
    <button type="submit" class="pull-right btn btn-success" name="btnAddTemplate" id="btnAddTemplate"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i>  Save template</button>
</form>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

My jquery and ajax call is :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(e) {
            $(document).on("click", "#btnAddTemplate", function(e){
                var templateName = $("#txtTemplateName").val();
                var emailFrom = $("#txtEmailFrom").val();
                var emailSubject = $("#txtEmailSubject").val();
                var emailContent = $("#txtEmailContent").val();
                $.ajax({
                    url : "adding-new-template.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {templateName : templateName, emailFrom : emailFrom, emailSubject : emailSubject, emailContent : emailContent, status : "insert"},
                    beforeSend: function(){
                        $("#pleaseWait").show();
                    },
                    success: function(msg){
                        $("#pleaseWait").hide();
                        if(msg == "Added"){
                            $("#addedSuccess").html("De tamplate is succesvol toegevoegd.").fadeIn(300).fadeOut(10000);
                        }else{
                            $("#addedError").html("Er is iets misgelopen. De template is niet succesvol toegevoegd.").fadeIn(300).fadeOut(8000);
                        }
                    },

                    error: function(){
                        $("#pleaseWait").hide();
                        $("#addedError").html("Er is iets misgelopen. De template is niet succesvol toegevoegd.").fadeIn(300).fadeOut(8000);
                    }
                });
                e.preventDefault();
            });
        });

    </script>
```

And at the end my adding-new-template.php code is :

```
<?php
        session_start();
        include("config.php");
        global $kon;

        $templateName = $_POST["templateName"]; 
        $emailFrom = $_POST["emailFrom"];   
        $emailSubject = $_POST["emailSubject"]; 
        $emailContent = $_POST["emailContent"]; 
        $status = $_POST["status"];

        if($status == "insert"){
            if(mysqli_query($kon, "INSERT INTO emailtexts VALUES (NULL, '". $templateName ."', '". $emailFrom ."', '". $emailSubject ."', '". $emailContent ."')")){
                echo "Added";   
            }
        }else{
            if($status == "update"){

            }
        }
    ?>
```

And the email content I am trying to add is :

> Dear,
>
> Your password is changed. Your credentials are :
>
> Username : $username (The value) New password = $password (the value)
>
> Best regards

Comment: Tell us you are not sending that via Email. Tell us you are storing a hash and not plain text passwords. Tell us this isn't intended to be a live site.

Comment: C'mon man. It is not a live site. I am trying to explain what I am trying to do.

Comment: so, why have everyone work on your script for nothing then? sounds like homework.

Comment: I hate when people say *"I'm not that far along..."* or *"This site will not be public..."* or *"It's only for school, so security doesn't matter..."*. If teachers and professors are not talking about security from day one, they're doing it wrong. They're teaching sloppy and dangerous coding practices which students will have to unlearn later. I also hate it when folks say, *"I'll add security later..."*. If you don't have time to do it right the first time, when will you find the time to add it later?

Answer (score 0):

İ believe you have extra $ sign in front of that $var variable and you end up adding [variable variable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)

> A variable variable takes the value of a variable and treats that as the name of a variable. In the above example, hello, can be used as the name of a variable by using two dollar signs. i.e.

Comment: Thus how should I add a variable to the database, like {var} maybe or?

Comment: IS it possible to see the template you are making? maybe you did not put  quotation marks in right place so you end up getting $var instead of the variable it contains?

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
$var= "This is value of my variable";

$rez = mysqli_query($kon, "SELECT * FROM emailTexts WHERE id = 2");
$red = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rez);

echo "Test result : <br /><br />" . str_replace("$var", $var, $red["content"]);
```

But it's not really flexible, you should explain why you need to put a var in database.

If you are looking for a template, you can take exemple on this :

```
<?php

function parse($text, $data)
{
    // Loop to replace all the variables known as : {{[a-z_]+}}
    while (preg_match("/{{(\w+)}}/", $text, $matches) == 1)
    {
        // Keeping trace of the text you're going to replace
        $str_to_replace = $matches[0];
        // Retrieving only the name of the variable
        $var_to_seek = $matches[1];
        // Assigning the variable found
        $new_var = "";
        if (isset($data[$var_to_seek]))
            $new_var = $data[$var_to_seek];
        // Replacing the variable in the original string.
        $text = str_replace($str_to_replace, $new_var, $text);
    }
    return $text;
}

$str = "Hello {{firstname}} {{name}}.{{unsetvar}} {{sentence}}";

echo parse($str, array("firstname" => "John", "name" => "Doe", "sentence" => "Templates are cool."));
//Output is "Hello John Doe. Templates are cool."
```

Also, don't forget to escape your values before inserting in database.

Comment: It won't work. I a trying to make email templates. Thus, if user for example changes his password, I want to be able to edit the email which is send to him. But in that email I need to have a few dynamic variables, like password and username.

Comment: You should try a template then, I'll edit my answer @Boky

Comment: My template system is perfect for you then, juste change $var to {{var}} and pass your string through my function @Boky